# Кодировка текста в C# (CP1163)

Tags: c#, перекодировка, кодировка

Есть определенный код который получает и выводит листинг из БД (MySQL).

Не могу одолеть один столбец, там данные (текст) лежат в кодировке `cp1163`.

Соответственно в листинге отображаются кракозябры.

Знатоки, подскажите пожалуйста  как можно  штатными средствами C#  перекодировать полученное в `cp1251`.

Пробовал указать `set names` при подключении, но MySQL не понимает такой кодировки.

Comment: cp1663 это не опечатка?

Comment: Извиняюсь) Очепятка.  Исправил)

Comment: Не надо тебе в 1251!

Comment: А может в консерватории исправить? В смысле, переделать столбец в utf8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Общий вид такой:

```
var sourceEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1163);
var resultEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251");
byte[] sourceBytes = utf8.GetBytes(text);
byte[] resultBytes = Encoding.Convert(sourceEncoding, resultEncoding, sourceBytes);
var result = resultEncoding.GetString(resultBytes);
```

Только вот Code Page найти я не смог. Вот [спецификация на CP1163](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.nls.doc/doc/r0051850.html), вы можете отнаследоваться от  `System.Text.Encoding` и реализовать у него `Convert`, `GetBytes`.

Comment: Хороший вариант, спасибо за подсказку. Попробую.

Comment: Эхм. А если кодирование потока байтов в cp1163 в utf-8 без потерь невозможно?

Comment: С `utf-8` аналогично, потерь не будет, если реализуете свой класс `Encoding`.

Comment: Я имел в виду следующую ситуацию. У вас есть поток байт, который представляет себе валидную строку, если интерпретировать его в кодировке cp1163. Вы предлагаете по сути следующую процедуру: (1) интерпретировать этот поток байт как строку в кодировке utf-8, (2) распаковать строку снова в байты, (3) этот поток байт превратить в другой поток байт, который соответствует другой кодировке, (4) сконвертировать это в строку. Но уже на шаге (1) вполне может быть потеря информации. А также на шаге (3).

Answer (score 8):

```
byte[] smthIn1163 = ...;
string s = new string(Encoding.GetEncoding(1163).GetChars(smthIn1163));
```

Ну и Encoding лучше создать один раз, а не в цикле.

Comment: А почему не стразу GetString?

Comment: @VladD, у меня подобный метод с GetString не срабатывал. Пришлось лепить велосипед как в первом посте.

Comment: @z668: Странно. А _почему именно_ не срабатывал? У меня всегда работало.

Comment: @ApInvent, чем GetEncoding лучше конструктора?

Comment: @VladD, забыл про этот метод.

Comment: @Qwertiy: из [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a3kf7c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): _GetEncoding returns a cached instance with default settings. You should use the constructors of derived classes to get an instance with different settings._

Comment: @Qwertiy Просто конструктор  - `protected`

Comment: @ApInvent, вот это я не заметил о_О