# Кириллица в JSON

Tags: php, c#, json, кодировка

Из БД достаю данные:

```
mysqli_query($db,"set names utf8");

$query = "SELECT * FROM devices";

$result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
$num_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);

$data = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{

  $data[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

На выходе получаю JSON массив в котором кириллица закодирована в Unicode.

При замены крайней строки на `json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)` Unicode заменяется на каракули.

Как можно решить эту проблему? JSON нужен для последующего вывода в приложении C#, может эту строку можно как то преобразовать непосредственно средствами C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего каракули у вас отображаются именно в браузере (или где вы там проверяете вывод echo).

Если на стороне C# предполагается обработка через нормальный десериализатор, например, через JSON.NET - просто оставьте как есть, без `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` - он сам правильно разэскейпит Unicode.

Если на стороне C# десериализатор не сможет разэскейпить - проставьте правильную кодировку ответа в PHP

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

и кракозябры пропадут.

Comment: Вопрос решил. Для нормального отображения в браузере использовал `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');` и добавление флага `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`. Но в C# продолжали приходить каракули.

Добавил `var str = new WebClient{Encoding = Encoding.UTF8}.DownloadString("...");` в код C# и всё заработало. На сколько мой метод костыльный? Для  десериализации JSON использую Newtonsoft JSON.

Comment: @dmepty не костыльный, все в родной кодировке идет. Для Newtonsoft JSON.Net можно убрать JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE, он должен понимать escaping. Но если заработало с Unicode - то разницы никакой.

Comment: Хорошо, благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы вам не конвертировать строку уже со стороны C# приложения? Вот ссылка на encoding строки [Encoding C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/451269/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-c-cp1163)

Comment: Хотя бы потому, что строки стоит сразу читать из базы данных в нужной кодировке. А не читать в неправильной кодировке с "перекодированием". "Перекодирование" - это костыль вместо исправления проблемы, который проблему просто маскирует и добавляет трудноуловимые баги с потерей символов, которых нет в одной из кодировок.